# Use thumbnail gallery to toggle multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I currently have a thumbnail gallery using `onclick`/jQuery/JavaScript, although it all works fine I think it will be confusing for the user to have to click a thumbnail to turn it on and then click it again to turn it off, before moving on to the next.

I currently have 8 thumbnails/larger images and I have typed this code out 8 times with different ids:

```
function toggle_visibility(chLoTog) {
    var e = document.getElementById(chLoTog);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
    else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

---

I'm new to jQuery and I bet there is a way of not having to type this code out 8 times. What I really want the code to is:

1. Click a thumbnail and relevant image appears
2. Click on another thumbnail which hides current thumbnail and shows new thumbnail
3. To be able to this in a random order.

I hope all this makes sense.

Comment: Could you add a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve very simply with jquery using a class and a data attribute on the thumbnail ie.

```
// HTML
// Add a class and a data attribute to the gallery thumbnal image
<img class="gallery-thumbnail" src="path/to/gallery-thumbnail.jpg" data-img="path/to/gallery-image.jpg" />

// jquery
// Bind a click function to each thumbnail image
$('.gallery-thumbnail').click(function(){
    // Hide all the currently showing gallery images
    $('.gallery-image').hide();

    // Get the id of the requested gallery image
    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('data-imge');

    // Show the requested gallery image
    $(id).show();
}):
```

You could even bind a click function to each of the gallery images so that a user can hide them by clicking on the image itself ie.

```
// Hide gallery image when clicked
$('.gallery-image').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Good point @JeffB not sure what I was thinking there, edited.